# If a set $X$ is countable, and there exists a bijection from $X$ to $Y$, then $Y$ is countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

My proof for this is as follows:

If $X$ is countable, there exists a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$. We have there is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$ as well, and so it follows that there is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $Y$. Thus, $|Y| = |\mathbb{N}|$, so $Y$ is countable.

Is this correct?

Comment: That is the gist of it, yes.

Comment: Does countable include finite for you?  For some it does, for some it does not.  If you are in the no camp, this is fine.  If you are in the yes camp, your second sentence is not correct.  You can patch it up, but it needs doing.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the case where $X$ is finite from where it is infinite. When $X$ is infinite you can do the bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, but if it is finite you will have to do something else.

Comment: Got it :) I think if $X$ is finite, I can just say, by the existence of the bijection between $X$ and $Y$, $|Y| = |X| = n$, where $n$ is the number of elements in $X$ (i.e. some number $\geq 0$). So, $Y$ is finite and thus countable.

Comment: @HisokaMoroh yes, that will work!

Comment: You don't have to separate the cases. Instead you note that since there's a bijection $X\to Y$ there's an injection $Y\to X$ and by definition one $X\to\mathbb N$ so there's a injection from $Y\to\mathbb N$ which means that $Y$ is countable.

Comment: @skyking Yeah, that'll work as well!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is correct.  If you want to be pedantic about it then you might mention that composing bijections gives a bijection, which is why you get a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $Y$.